# How do you debug MySQL stored procedures?

Tags: mysql, database, debugging, stored-procedures

My current process for debugging stored procedures is very simple. I create a table called "debug" where I insert variable values from the stored procedure as it runs. This allows me to see the value of any variable at a given point in the script, but is there a better way to debug MySQL stored procedures?

Comment: Are there any GUI options for non-Windows users? Having to run a copy of Windows just to debug stored procedures is a bit of a jump. And most of the table-insert options fail if you're in a transaction that you're about to rollback.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I do something very similar to you.

I'll usually include a DEBUG param that defaults to false and I can set to true at run time.  Then wrap the debug statements into an "If DEBUG"  block.

I also use a logging table with many of my jobs so that I can review processes and timing.  My Debug code gets output there as well.  I include the calling param name, a brief description, row counts affected (if appropriate), a comments field and a time stamp.

Good debugging tools is one of the sad failings of all SQL platforms.

Comment: Not all platforms @Bob Probst , sybase debugging tools are quiet decent with breakpoint debug for trigger and stored procedures

Answer (score 85):

The following `debug_msg` procedure can be called to simply output a debug message to the console:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `debug_msg`$$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test_procedure`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE debug_msg(enabled INTEGER, msg VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
  IF enabled THEN
    select concat('** ', msg) AS '** DEBUG:';
  END IF;
END $$

CREATE PROCEDURE test_procedure(arg1 INTEGER, arg2 INTEGER)
BEGIN
  SET @enabled = TRUE;

  call debug_msg(@enabled, 'my first debug message');
  call debug_msg(@enabled, (select concat_ws('','arg1:', arg1)));
  call debug_msg(TRUE, 'This message always shows up');
  call debug_msg(FALSE, 'This message will never show up');
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Then run the test like this:

```
CALL test_procedure(1,2)
```

It will result in the following output:

```
** DEBUG:
** my first debug message
** DEBUG:
** arg1:1
** DEBUG:
** This message always shows up
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for FUNCTIONS and I have no idea why. It always gives "Error Code: 1415. Not allowed to return a result set from a function". Is there any recourse?

Comment: @PatrickM Functions cannot return rows ("result") while this debug procedure relies on it (the debug messages are resultsets returned in the procedure call). In functions, you may only `INSERT INTO my_log_table (message) VALUES (msg)` and maybe retrieve all debug messages once function calls are over (ie: you're back in the procedure)

Comment: This aproach is good but writing to console isn't effective on MySQL Workbench like IDEs. because every "select" statement opens new result pane. I think it is better to create a temporary log table to log error messages with time stamp and procedure name

Answer (score 37):

**How to debug a MySQL stored procedure.**

Poor mans debugger:

1. Create a table called logtable with two columns, `id INT` and `log VARCHAR(255)`.
2. Make the id column autoincrement.
3. Use this procedure:

   ```
   delimiter //
   DROP PROCEDURE `log_msg`//
   CREATE PROCEDURE `log_msg`(msg VARCHAR(255))
   BEGIN
       insert into logtable select 0, msg;
   END
   ```
4. Put this code anywhere you want to log a message to the table.

   ```
   call log_msg(concat('myvar is: ', myvar, ' and myvar2 is: ', myvar2));
   ```

It's a nice quick and dirty little logger to figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 31):

Yes, there is a specialized tools for this kind of thing - [MySQL Debugger](http://www.mydebugger.com).
[image]

Comment: i was so eager to try it out. Unfortunately it is a total wreckage. I get "function coalesce does not exist" error message suppsedly from mysql, as a result the GUI branches incorrectly through SP code (although MySQL runs it correctly). Not to mention the "DECLARE var DEFAULT value" local variables. They just show up as NULL when they clearly are not. Oh, and also "Undeclared identifier: 'FETCH_RADIUS_DISTSORT'" where that was a compiled statement. Not recommended.

Comment: It's not perfect but my trial with this has been a very different experience to that reported by @kellogs above. The tool is nice and lightweight and seems to do just the job needed without any bloat. It was a far better experience for me than any of the other tools trialled (i.e. Visual Studio, Toad and dbForge Studio, all of which had major flaws - would describe all of these as a "total wreckage" in comparison). Not sure whether this is because the function being debugged didn't include any of the faulty constructs or whether the issues have been fixed.

Comment: I also found this tool to be quite useful for debugging my stored procedures.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to use it for trigger. Not sure there is a way using it.

Answer (score 20):

There are [GUI tools for debugging stored procedures](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/code-debugger.html) / functions and scripts in MySQL. A decent tool that dbForge Studio for MySQL, has rich functionality and stability.

Comment: Difficult to find what platforms that debug tool runs on. Seems to run on Windows. Anything else?

Answer (score 13):

Debugger for mysql was good but it's not free. This is what I use now:

```
DELIMITER GO$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS resetLog

GO$

Create Procedure resetLog() 
BEGIN   
    create table if not exists log (ts timestamp default current_timestamp, msg varchar(2048)) engine = myisam; 
    truncate table log;
END; 

GO$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS doLog 

GO$

Create Procedure doLog(in logMsg nvarchar(2048))
BEGIN  
  insert into log (msg) values(logMsg);
END;

GO$
```

Usage in stored procedure:

```
call dolog(concat_ws(': ','@simple_term_taxonomy_id',  @simple_term_taxonomy_id));
```

usage of stored procedure:

```
call resetLog ();
call stored_proc();
select * from log;
```

Comment: For the hobby stored procedure writer using db Client IDE's (DataGrip), this is the way.

Answer (score 10):

Another way is presented here

http://gilfster.blogspot.co.at/2006/03/debugging-stored-procedures-in-mysql.html

with custom debug mySql procedures and logging tables.

You can also just place a simple select in your code and see if it is executed.

```
SELECT 'Message Text' AS `Title`;
```

I got this idea from

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,78155,78225#msg-78225

Also somebody created a template for custom debug procedures on GitHub.

See here

http://www.bluegecko.net/mysql/debugging-stored-procedures/
https://github.com/CaptTofu/Stored-procedure-debugging-routines

Was mentioned here

[How to catch any exception in triggers and store procedures for mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908453/how-to-catch-any-exception-in-triggers-and-store-procedures-for-mysql)

Answer (score 8):

I'm late to the party, but brought more beer:

http://ocelot.ca/blog/blog/2015/03/02/the-ocelotgui-debugger/
and
https://github.com/ocelot-inc/ocelotgui

I tried, and it seems pretty stable, supporting Breakpoints and Variable inspection.

It's not a complete suite (just 4,1 Mb) but helped me a lot!

How it works:
It integrates with your mysql client (I'm using Ubuntu 14.04), and after you execute:

```
$install
$setup yourFunctionName
```

It installs a new database at your server, that control the debugging process. So:

```
$debug yourFunctionName('yourParameter')
```

will give you a chance to step by step walk your code, and "refreshing" your variables you can better view what is going on inside your code.

*Important Tip: while debugging, maybe you will change (re-create the procedure). After a re-creation, execute: $exit and $setup before a new $debug*

This is an alternative to "insert" and "log" methods.
Your code remains free of additional "debug" instructions.

Screenshot:

[image: ocelot breakpoint stepping]

Answer (score 7):

I just simply place select statements in key areas of the stored procedure to check on current status of data sets, and then comment them out (--select...) or remove them before production.

Comment: Yes I do exactly the same. I place select statement and check the status of the tables and related values. I sometime use temporary table to insert values in tables and once the solution is found, I remove temporary tables and those select statements.

Answer (score 6):

MySQL Connector/Net 6.6 has a feature to [Debug Stored Procedures and Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-visual-studio-debugger.html)

> **Installing the Debugger**
>
> To enable the stored procedure debugger:
>
> - For Connector/Net 6.6: Install Connector/Net 6.6 and choose the    Complete option.
> - For Connector/Net 6.7 and later: Install the product MySQL for Visual    Studio, to which the stored procedure debugger belongs.
>
> **Starting the Debugger**
>
> To start the debugger, follow these steps:
>
> - Choose a connection in the Visual Studio Server Explorer.
> - Expand the Stored Procedures folder. Only stored procedures can be    debugged directly. To debug a user-defined function, create a stored
>   procedure that calls the function.
> - Click on a stored procedure node, then right-click and from the    context menu choose Debug Routine.

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *"404 | Page Not Found"*

Answer (score 5):

MySql Connector/NET also includes a stored procedure debugger integrated in visual studio as of version 6.6,
You can get the installer and the source here:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Some documentation / screenshots: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-debugger.html

You can follow the annoucements here:
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,561817,561817#msg-561817

UPDATE: The MySql for Visual Studio was split from Connector/NET into a separate product, you can pick it (including the debugger) from here https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/1.2.html  (still free & open source).

DISCLAIMER: I was the developer who authored the Stored procedures debugger engine for MySQL for Visual Studio product.

Comment: There is an issue with multi-host connection string when using MySQL and Connector .NET. I have explained the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56274136/connectionstring-for-connecting-3-master-nodes-to-mysql).. .I was wondering if anyone is going to look into this? This has caused quite a bit of problem for many of us .Net developers who use MySQL...

Comment: Sorry to hear that, I no longer work at Oracle, and have no a lot of free time, I suggest getting in touch with MySQL support.

Answer (score 4):

The first and stable debugger for MySQL is in dbForge Studio for MySQL

Answer (score 3):

I had use two different tools to debug procedures and functions:

1. dbForge - many functional mysql GUI.
2. MyDebugger - specialized tool for debugging ... handy tool for debugging.[vote http://tinyurl.com/voteimg](http://tinyurl.com/voteimg)

Answer (score 3):

MySQL user defined variable (shared in session) could be used as logging output:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE Foo(tableName VARCHAR(128))
BEGIN
  SET @stmt = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', tableName);
  PREPARE pStmt FROM @stmt;
  EXECUTE pStmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE pStmt;
  -- uncomment after debugging to cleanup
  -- SET @stmt = null;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

```
call Foo('foo');
select @stmt;
```

will output:

```
SELECT * FROM foo
```

Answer (score 2):

Toad mysql.  There is a freeware version
http://www.quest.com/toad-for-mysql/

Comment: I've used Toad for years but wasn't aware it had any special features for debugging sprocs. Can you clarify how you use Toad to do so?

Comment: Looked at Toad 6.3 for mysql just now, looks like there is debug feature with breakpoints and everything.  Do you mean that the debug feature is not working?  Or maybe your version is older & doesn't include debug feature?

Answer (score 1):

Answer corresponding to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273437/how-do-you-debug-mysql-stored-procedures#15687954) by @Brad Parks
Not sure about the MySQL version, but mine was 5.6, hence a little bit tweaking works:

I created a function `debug_msg` which is function (not procedure) and returns text(no character limit) and then call the function as SELECT `debug_msg`(params) AS `my_res_set`, code as below:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `debug_msg`(`enabled` INT(11), `msg` TEXT) RETURNS text CHARSET latin1
    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    IF enabled=1 THEN
    return concat('** DEBUG:', "** ", msg);
    END IF;
END

DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `proc_func_call`(
 IN RegionID VARCHAR(20),
 IN RepCurrency INT(11),
 IN MGID INT(11),
 IN VNC VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
    SET @enabled = TRUE;
    SET @mainQuery = "SELECT * FROM Users u";
    SELECT `debug_msg`(@enabled, @mainQuery) AS `debug_msg1`;
    SET @lastQuery = CONCAT(@mainQuery, " WHERE u.age>30);
    SELECT `debug_msg`(@enabled, @lastQuery) AS `debug_msg2`;
END $$
DELIMITER
```