# Step through mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Is it possible to step through a mysql stored procedure, watching the values of variables at each step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this related question for some ideas related to debugging stored procedures:

[How do you debug MySQL stored procedures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273437/how-do-you-debug-mysql-stored-procedures)

---

Edit:

I tried out the trial of [Debugger for MySQL](http://www.mydebugger.com/) and it looks promising.   You might give that a try.

Comment: yeah i saw that post. that approach is plain clumsy. but i did that anyway. was just looking for a better way. will definitely give this software u mentioned a try

Comment: The trial isn't bad.  I was able to put together a CALL line and set breakpoints and check the values along the way.