# Debugging MySQL Triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers

I love triggers for one reason - they just work. I hate triggers for one reason - when they don't work, forget about trying to debug. O the sweet frustration.

Basically, I want to see THE update, delete, insert, etc query that was ran. I want to see that query ... somewhere, in my terminal or a log, exactly how and when MySQL executes it, and possibly any corresponding output/errors. Thoughts/hacks?

I'm trying to debug an update query with a few joins and what not. My queries are much more complex but for brevity here's an example.

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER ireallyhateyourightnow AFTER UPDATE ON watch_this_table
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 IF (OLD.my_value != NEW.my_value) THEN
  update 
   my_table
  set 
   my_column = NEW.my_value;
 END IF;
END|
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is some additional context that may help influence a suggestion or answer. Again, I'm less interested in semantics/syntax and more interested in seeing MySQL run the query but by all means, I'm open to anything at this point.

- Strace does not work/show query.
- Non-replicated environment BUT if the bin logs show trigger statements I will certainly set this up.
- Does "show full processlist" show trigger execution and/or statements executed within (I never see them after running show full processlist as fast as perl can run it but I might just be missing it)?
- General query log does not show these queries (certainly not the error log).
- I'm not using aliases (anymore).
- No syntax errors when creating the trigger.
- The IF statement works.
- When I insert the NEW values into a "test/temp" table and manually run the update query it works (I've even went so far as to actually inserting the whole update query)
- I can't show you the query but as I just mentioned, it works when I run manually if that helps.
- I've removed all erroneous characters, tabs, carriage returns, newlines, etc.
- The MySQL socket would only show local connection/data but not MySQL internal workings, I think.
- MyISAM so INNODB logs aren't an option
- lsof didn't seem to show anything else to be of use.
- I'm using MySQL 5.0.77 on CentOS 5.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [debug triggers](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/code-debugger.html) using [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/). Try trial version.

There is a detailed description of the trigger debugging process in the documentation: Debugging \ Debugging Stored Routines \ How To: Start Trigger Debugging.

Comment: Yea, step into is grayed out. Presumably because it's a trial?

Comment: The 'Step Into' command has to be active from the stored procedure code. Have you followed the step by step instruction (How To: Start Trigger Debugging)?

Comment: Thank you Devart! Very nice piece of software.

Comment: I have not gotten it to work! When I set a break point in my trigger (which is an after insert trigger) I debug my insert statement and I press ctrl + f5 to jump to the break point and I get that the trigger executed with an error. I just want to make sure, this implies the error is happening before my break point? And I am setting/jumping to my break point correctly?

Comment: You should write INSERT statement in your procedure. Then start debugging the procedure, and click Step Into on INSERT statement. Note, that trigger must be compiled before with debug info.

Answer (score 16):

There's [an alternate way of testing it by having a temporary `debug` table](http://gilfster.blogspot.com/2006/03/debugging-stored-procedures-in-mysql.html). In the example here, they create it in an own `debug` database.

**Step 1:** Create a table

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS debug;
CREATE TABLE debug (
  proc_id varchar(100) default NULL,
  debug_output text,
  line_id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  PRIMARY KEY  (line_id)
)
```

**Step 2:** Create debug SPs to fill the debug table

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `debug_insert` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `debug_insert`(in p_proc_id varchar(100),in p_debug_info text)
begin
  insert into debug (proc_id,debug_output)
  values (p_proc_id,p_debug_info);
end $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `debug_on` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `debug_on`(in p_proc_id varchar(100))
begin
  call debug_insert(p_proc_id,concat('Debug Started :',now()));
end $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `debug_off` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `debug_off`(in p_proc_id varchar(100))
begin
  call debug_insert(p_proc_id,concat('Debug Ended :',now()));
  select debug_output from debug where proc_id = p_proc_id order by line_id;
  delete from debug where proc_id = p_proc_id;
end $$
```

**Step 3:** Invoke the debug SPs in your trigger

Like this,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test_debug()
begin
declare l_proc_id varchar(100) default 'test_debug';
  call debug_on(l_proc_id);
  call debug_insert(l_proc_id,'Testing Debug');
  call debug_off(l_proc_id);
end $$
```

As a result the debug table would be filled as follows,

```
+------------------------------------+
| debug_output                       |
+------------------------------------+
| Debug Started :2006-03-24 16:10:33 |
| Testing Debug                      |
| Debug Ended :2006-03-24 16:10:33   |
+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This works nicely except for the debug_off() procedure which fails on the select statement when used with a trigger, as here, or with a function since neither will allow you to return a result set. Remove that (and the delete statement that follows) and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

**MYSQL PROCEDURE => incron => tail -f 'mysql_dynamic.log'**

A Stored Procedure can be invoked inside a trigger but must return nothing

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `DYN_LOG` (IN s VARCHAR(500))
BEGIN
SELECT s into outfile '/var/spool/incron/mysql_dynamic_spool/foo_file';
DO SLEEP(.1);   // create a gap beetween multiple shuts
END
```

Now anywhere in a trigger you can invoke

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trig_name` BEFORE UPDATE ON `tb_name` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
CALL DYN_LOG(concat_ws('\t',NEW.col1,NEW.col2));
... 
// rest of the code
END
```

for Linux machines `apt-get install incron` [(debian incron tutorial)](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/incron)

Create the folder in which mysql will inject foo_file

```
mkdir -m 777 /var/spool/incron/mysql_dynamic_spool
incrontab -e
```

and add following  incron job

```
/var/spool/incron/mysql_dynamic_spool IN_CREATE /path/foo_file_procesor $@/$#
```

Create executable script "/path/foo_file_procesor"

```
#!/bin/sh
# // $1 is the foo_file absolute addres
body="$(cat $1)"  #// read file content
rm  $1
log=/var/log/mysql_dynamic.log    #// message collector
echo "`date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`\t== dyn_log ==\t$body">>$log
exit 0
```

Now watch the collector file

```
tail -f /var/log/mysql_dynamic.log
```