# How can I print stored procedure query in codeignitor model?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I want to print SQL query from my stored procedure.

My procedure like:

```
$Insert-array = my values;

$query = $this->db->query("CALL Category(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,@id)", $Insert-array);
```

I use `print_r($this->db->last_query());`.

My result looks like this:

```
CALL Category(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,@id)
```

When I use print query statement.. now how can I print the SQL statement query from the stored procedure?

Comment: do you mean that you would like to see the stored procedure with the values instead of placeholders?

Comment: yes i want to execure whole sql query

Comment: I think you are asking for queries written inside stored procedure ?

Comment: If you want to print the actual SQL commands written within the `stored procedure` then you cannot do so automagically

Comment: you can enable logs in the sql server for a period and see what reaches the server.

Answer (score 0):

I'll usually include a DEBUG param that defaults to false and I can set to true at run time. Then wrap the debug statements into an "If DEBUG" block.

I also use a logging table with many of my jobs so that I can review processes and timing. My Debug code gets output there as well. I include the calling param name, a brief description, row counts affected (if appropriate), a comments field and a time stamp.

for more about debugging please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314771/print-debugging-info-from-stored-procedure-in-mysql)