# mysql: can I send debug messages to log file using mysql commands?

Tags: mysql, logging

I would like to debug my stored procedures properly, the easiest way i can think of is to be able to send debug messages to the log file of mysql. is that possible ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the User Defined function that is available here...

https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_log

and then use it anywhere in the select query like...

```
mysql> SELECT log_error(concat(now(), 'error in selecting line 13'));
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| log_error(concat(now(), 'error in selecting line 13')) |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                      0 |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

# tail /var/log/mysqld.log
2010-12-02 03:16:03error in selecting line 13
```

Comment: dead link, but got the idea

Answer (score 2):

As I have not heard of anything like that I will recommend you this http://benjisimon.blogspot.com/2007/02/debugging-mysql-stored-procedures.html

or read this topic [How do you debug MySQL stored procedures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273437/how-do-you-debug-mysql-stored-procedures)

Comment: welp if there isn't any way to send messages to the log file, the method of creating a log table and inserting log strings to that table is a suitable answer for me. thanks